# C Lang - Struct Array and Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

I have written a simple code to read a directory then sort the files by last modified time,but the following code will crash because Segmentation fault (core dumped)，（occur when try to access the lsf[0] and lsf[1] ），how to solve the problem，please help，thanks：

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char *name;
  unsigned long lasted;
} sort_file;

char *make_path(char *path) {
  char *endp = path + strlen(path);
  *endp++ = '/';
  return endp;
}

int main(int arc, char **argv) {

  const char *n_dir = "/home/psycho/Pictures";
  char *dir_name = strdup(n_dir);

  char *endp = make_path(dir_name);

  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *ent;
  struct stat attr;

  int size = 150;
  int count = 0;
  sort_file **lsf = malloc(size * sizeof(sort_file *));
  printf("[Logging] : %d => %d  \n", sizeof(sort_file), sizeof(sort_file *));
  if ((dir = opendir(n_dir)) != NULL) {
    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {

      if (ent->d_name[0] == '.') {
        continue;
      } else if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR) {
        strcpy(endp, ent->d_name);
        stat(dir_name, &attr);

        lsf[count] = malloc(sizeof(sort_file));
        lsf[count]->lasted = (unsigned long)attr.st_mtime;
        lsf[count]->name = malloc((strlen(ent->d_name) )* sizeof(char));

        sprintf(lsf[count]->name, "%s", ent->d_name);
        printf("[Logging] : --- %lu --- %d --- %s  \n", lsf[count]->lasted,
               count, lsf[count]->name);


        count++;

      }
    }
    closedir(dir);

  } else {
    return 0;
  }

  while (count--) {
    printf("[Logging] : --- %lu --- %d --- %s  \n", lsf[count]->lasted, count,
           lsf[count]->name);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc((strlen(ent->d_name) )` --> `malloc((strlen(ent->d_name)+1 )`

Comment: `strcpy(endp, ent->d_name);` : `endp` is pointing to an invalid area.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Tanks very much

Comment: If your question was just "how do you debug a segmentation fault", you shouldn't have posted all this code. That causes you to get unhelpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

This code includes some memory panics, depend on different compilers different errors may occur.

1. In `make_path`, `endp` is pointing to last character of `dir_name` (`'\0'`) and is trying to change it from `'\0'` to `'/'` without inserting the string trailing char (`'\0'`) at the end and `realloc` one more character for `dir_name`
2. In `main`, `const char *n_dir = "/home/psycho/Pictures";` do not need to be defined as pointer because length is known at compile time. In fact it should be changed to: `const char n_dir[] = "/home/psycho/Pictures";`
3. In `main`, `endp` is not allocated at all so `strcpy(endp, ent->d_name);` copies to restricted memory spaces
4. In `main`, `lsf[count]->name = malloc((strlen(ent->d_name) )* sizeof(char));` should allocate one more unit because of trailing `'\0'`: `lsf[count]->name = malloc((strlen(ent->d_name)`**+ 1**`)* sizeof(char));`

At last I noticed a logical error:
`if (ent->d_name[0] == '.') {`... makes program to skip '**.**', '**..**', and all other directories starting with '**.**' (Linux hidden folders). You can use `0 == (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") * strcmp(ent->d_name, ".."))`